# logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, None, 8922) vs (None, 8922))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, attention-model

i am trying to implement keras SeqSelfAttention layer in my model. i get the summary of my model but when i fit it on train and valid data it gives me error.
following is the architecture of my model.

```
import keras
from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention


model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=150854,
                                 output_dim=100, input_length=1500,embeddings_initializer=keras.initializers.Constant(emb_matrix),
                               trainable=False))
model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(units=128,
                                                       return_sequences=True)))
model.add(SeqSelfAttention(attention_activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=8922, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary(line_length=100)

Model: "sequential_5"
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                                 Output Shape                            Param #        
====================================================================================================
embedding_11 (Embedding)                     (None, 1500, 100)                       15085400       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_11 (Bidirectional)             (None, 1500, 256)                       234496         
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
seq_self_attention_5 (SeqSelfAttention)      (None, None, 256)                       16449          
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                              (None, None, 8922)                      2292954        
====================================================================================================
Total params: 17,629,299
Trainable params: 2,543,899
Non-trainable params: 15,085,400
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

when i fit the model

```
history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid),epochs=30, batch_size=16, callbacks=[callback, chk])
```

i get following error:

```
Epoch 1/30
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-f96237c73ff2> in <module>()
----> 1 history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid),epochs=30, batch_size=16, callbacks=[callback, chk])

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    870       initializers = []
--> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    872     finally:
    873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 726             *args, **kwds))
    727 
    728     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2967       args, kwargs = None, None
   2968     with self._lock:
-> 2969       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2970     return graph_function
   2971 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3359 
   3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3363 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3204             arg_names=arg_names,
   3205             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3206             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3207         self._function_attributes,
   3208         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    989 
--> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    991 
    992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    632             xla_context.Exit()
    633         else:
--> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    635         return out
    636 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:756 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:203 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:152 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:256 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1608 binary_crossentropy
        K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits), axis=-1)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4979 binary_crossentropy
        return nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py:174 sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
        (logits.get_shape(), labels.get_shape()))

    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, None, 8922) vs (None, 8922))
```

i tried to resolve it with Reshape layer:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=150854,
                                 output_dim=100, input_length=1500,embeddings_initializer=keras.initializers.Constant(emb_matrix),
                               trainable=False))
model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(units=128,
                                                       return_sequences=True)))
model.add(SeqSelfAttention(attention_activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.Reshape((8922,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=8922, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary(line_length=100)

Model: "sequential_6"
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                                 Output Shape                            Param #        
====================================================================================================
embedding_12 (Embedding)                     (None, 1500, 100)                       15085400       
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_12 (Bidirectional)             (None, 1500, 256)                       234496         
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
seq_self_attention_6 (SeqSelfAttention)      (None, None, 256)                       16449          
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_4 (Reshape)                          (None, 8922)                            0              
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                              (None, 8922)                            79611006       
====================================================================================================
Total params: 94,947,351
Trainable params: 79,861,951
Non-trainable params: 15,085,400
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

still getting the following error:

```
Epoch 1/30
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-f96237c73ff2> in <module>()
----> 1 history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid),epochs=30, batch_size=16, callbacks=[callback, chk])

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    886         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    887         # stateless function.
--> 888         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    889     else:
    890       _, _, _, filtered_flat_args = \

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2941        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2942     return graph_function._call_flat(
-> 2943         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2944 
   2945   @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1917       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1918       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1919           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1920     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1921         args,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    558               inputs=args,
    559               attrs=attrs,
--> 560               ctx=ctx)
    561         else:
    562           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 6144000 values, but the requested shape has 142752
     [[node sequential_6/reshape_4/Reshape (defined at <ipython-input-64-f96237c73ff2>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_52586]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential_6/reshape_4/Reshape:
 sequential_6/seq_self_attention_6/MatMul_3 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_self_attention/seq_self_attention.py:182)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Shall be thankful for help

Comment: use a GlobalPooling/Flatten layer after SeqSelfAttention

Comment: i tried with flatten layer too, but it did not resolved. i think there is problem with shape of my data. my x_train. shape(47337, 1500) and y_train.shape is (47337,8922). It seems that the SeqSelfAttention layer is expecting all the time-steps. i don't know how should i convert my shape of data.